# column ambigously defined error

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

i have this code

```
select people_id,first_name 
FROM people , PUBAUTHOR_PEOPLE 
WHERE people.people_id = PUBAUTHOR_PEOPLE. people_id
```

and it says column ambigously defined does anybody know why and how to fix that?

Comment: And Oracle cannot tell which table `people_id` comes from.  Use table aliases (and proper `join` syntax).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's complaining because both tables have a column called 'people_id', so you have to specify which table to read it from (even though it will be the same because of the join condition), so something like:

```
SELECT      people.people_id,
            first_name 

FROM        people, PUBAUTHOR_PEOPLE 

WHERE       people.people_id = PUBAUTHOR_PEOPLE.people_id
```

Comment: thank you because i don't use this site for answers i use it to solve my problems, but i want to understand it also

Answer (score 1):

You should add table name before your coulmn names as below

```
select people.people_id,people.first_name 
FROM people , PUBAUTHOR_PEOPLE 
WHERE people.people_id = PUBAUTHOR_PEOPLE. people_id
```

I recommended you to use aliases as below to make code more readable

```
select p.people_id,p.first_name 
FROM people p, PUBAUTHOR_PEOPLE pp
WHERE p.people_id = pp.people_id
```

I also recommended you to use joins as below

```
select p.people_id,p.first_name 
FROM people p
join PUBAUTHOR_PEOPLE pp on p.people_id = pp.people_id
```

It is more readable now, isn't it?

Comment: im trying to select countrys, but i only have the country_id and need to get them from another table how would i do that join

Comment: try this `join country c on c.country_id = p.coutry_id` I guess country is in `country` table and `country_id` is in both `country` and `people` tables

Comment: SELECT      first_name,last_name,MAIL_COUNTRY_ID,EMAIL
FROM        people, PUBAUTHOR_PEOPLE 
WHERE       people.people_id = PUBAUTHOR_PEOPLE.people_id 
JOIN 
country
from countries
where country c on c.country_id = p.coutry_id

Comment: is my code it says that it is not ended properly why and how can i fix this

Comment: try this `select p.people_id,p.first_name 
FROM people p
join PUBAUTHOR_PEOPLE pp on p.people_id = pp.people_id
JOIN country from countries where country c on c.country_id = p.coutry_id`

Comment: it says missing keyword

Comment: `select p.people_id,p.first_name  
FROM people p 
join PUBAUTHOR_PEOPLE pp on p.people_id = pp.people_id 
JOIN country c on c.country_id = p.coutry_id`  now I think it is correct ;)